# Redirect loop due to "Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected in"

Tags: php, redirect

I'm trying to redirect to a URL and as it can be provided by the user, it may be somewhat invalid thus producing the warning message

```
Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected in
```

and oddly enough PHP generates a redirect to the same page thus creating a redirect loop.
How can I properly check the string to ensure there are no invalid characters in the URL? I tried

```
if (false === filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) die('Sorry, but no');
```

but it also failed on valid URLs that have non-English characters encoded in them.
I also tried `strpos($url, "\n")` and similar `"\r"` but probably some "newlines" are different and weren't detected.

In addition to my question on detecting it, isn't creating a redirect loop a faulty behavior by PHP that should be reported in that case?

Comment: You can use this function: `urlencode()`

Comment: @Collector some additional code will be helpful. Maybe the code of the whole redirect. Also you could consider using `.htaccess`

Comment: @divaka My question remained with a general nature on purpose so answers could be beneficial to all.

Comment: @Perry this doesn't answer my question. I wish to detect an invalid URL, not to encode as something irrelevant.

Comment: @Collector Could you give us some example URL that do not pass the filter but it's valid? I think I have a clue what should happening.

Comment: And as an addition take a look at this as a solution for you: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php#104160

Comment: @divaka The function from the manual did work so if you want to write it as an answer I'll accept it. The other solutions didn't validate this valid example URL http://colnect.com/tool/redirs/%A8%D7%91%D7%9B%D7%A2%D7%3Dyreuq_hcraes%3Fstluser%2Fmoc.ebutuoy.www or did validate this invalid URL http://colnect.com/tool/redirs/DB%0D%EB%0D%28%1D%DB%0D%0B%0D%AB%0D%BB%0D%0B%0D%1B%0D%+EB%0D%8B%0DK%0D8%1D%28%1D%18%1D%+F8%1D%8B%0Dh%1D%0B%0D%CB%0D%08%1D%EB%0DH%1D%=yreuq_hcraes?stluser/moc.ebutuoy.www

Comment: @Collector It's not a function I wrote, so I don't know if it will be fair to post it here as mine. I'm glad I've helped. You could upvote the comment in order to be helpful for other people.

Comment: @divaka once you mention the source, there's nothing unfair about it. If u prefer not to, I'll answer my own question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I found in php.net comments and make a function out of it:

```
function isValidURI($uri) {
    $res = filter_var ($uri, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
    if ($res) return $res;
    // Check if it has unicode chars.
    $l = mb_strlen ($uri);
    if ($l !== strlen ($uri)) {
        // Replace wide chars by “X”.
        $s = str_repeat (' ', $l);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $l; ++$i) {
            $ch = mb_substr ($uri, $i, 1);
            $s [$i] = strlen ($ch) > 1 ? 'X' : $ch;
        }
        // Re-check now.
        $res = filter_var ($s, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
        if ($res) {    $uri = $res; return 1;    }
    }
}
```

> FILTER_VALIDATE_URL does not support internationalized domain name
>   (IDN). Valid or not, no domain name with Unicode chars on it will pass
>   validation.
>
> The logic is simple. A non-ascii char is more than one byte long. We
>   replace every one of those chars by "X" and check again.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php#104160

Hope this to be helpful to someone else as well.

Comment: Thanks. This function works very well for the URLs I was testing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP's http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php function.
"On seriously malformed URLs, parse_url() may return FALSE."

Comment: This doesn't work for this valid example URL http://colnect.com/tool/redirs/%A8%D7%91%D7%9B%D7%A2%D7%3Dyreuq_hcraes%3Fstluser%2Fmoc.ebutuoy.www